# Fuzzy string matching of a list of character vectors to a character vector

Tags: r, string, fuzzy-comparison

I have a list of character vectors and a single character vector. I would like to perform a fuzzy matching in R between each element of the list (a character vector) to each element of a character vector (a character string) and return the maximum similarity score for each combination. Below is a toy example:

```
a <- c("brown fox", "lazy dog", "white cat", "I don't know", "sunset", "never mind", "excuse me")
b <- c("very late", "do not cross", "sunrise", "long vacation")
c <- c("toy example", "green apple", "tall building", "good rating", "accommodating")
mylist <- list(a,b,c)

charvec <- c("brown dog", "lazy cat", "white dress", "I know that", "excuse me please", "tall person", "new building", "good example", "green with envy", "zebra crossing")
```

Now, I would like to fuzzy match each element in `mylist` with the first string in `charvec` and return the maximum similarity score out of the 7 scores. Likewise, I want to obtain the score for each combination of `mylist` and `charvec`.

My attempt so far:

Convert the strings in charvec to the column names of an empty data frame

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 3)), c(charvec))
```

Calculate the maximum similarity score between each combination using jarowinkler distance from RecordLinkage package (or if there is a better distance measure for matching phrases!!)

```
for (j in seq_along(mylist)) {
  for (i in length(ncol(df))) {
    df[[i,j]] <- max(jarowinkler(names(df)[i], mylist[[j]]))
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, I get only 3 scores in the first row with the rest of the values as NA.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `purrr` package

```
mylist <- setNames(mylist, c('a', 'b', 'c'))

library(purrr)

map_dfr(charvec,
    function(wrd, vec_list){
      setNames(map_df(vec_list, ~max(jarowinkler(wrd, .x))),
               names(vec_list)
      )

    },
    mylist)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
       a     b     c
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.911 0.580 0.603
 2 0.85  0.713 0.603
 3 0.842 0.557 0.515
 4 0.657 0.490 0.409
 5 0.912 0.489 0.659
 6 0.538 0.546 0.801
 7 0.716 0.547 0.740
 8 0.591 0.524 0.856
 9 0.675 0.509 0.821
10 0.619 0.587 0.630
```

If you'd like it wide:

```
map_dfc(charvec,
         function(wrd, vec_list) {
          set_names(list(map_dbl(vec_list, ~max(jarowinkler(wrd, .x)))),
                    wrd)
         },
        mylist
)

# A tibble: 3 x 10
  `brown dog` `lazy cat` `white dress` `I know that` `excuse me plea~ `tall person` `new building` `good example`
        <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1       0.911      0.85          0.842         0.657            0.912         0.538          0.716          0.591
2       0.580      0.713         0.557         0.490            0.489         0.546          0.547          0.524
3       0.603      0.603         0.515         0.409            0.659         0.801          0.740          0.856
# ... with 2 more variables: `green with envy` <dbl>, `zebra crossing` <dbl>
```

Comment: Perfect!! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First a helper function that returns the best match for a word given a character vector to check against. I'm using purrr package for mapping function as I prefer it over looping.

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(RecordLinkage)
a <- c("brown fox", "lazy dog", "white cat", "I don't know", "sunset", "never mind", "excuse me")
charvec <- c("brown dog", "lazy cat", "white dress", "I know that", "excuse me please", "tall person", "new building", "good example", "green with envy", "zebra crossing")

getBestMatch <- function(word, vector){
  purrr::map_dbl(charvec, ~RecordLinkage::jarowinkler(word, .x)) %>%
    magrittr::set_names(charvec) %>%
    which.max %>%
    names
}
```

Running the function produces following output:

```
> getBestMatch("brown fox", charvec)
[1] "brown dog"
```

Now that we have a helper function it's just a matter of calling it over elements of the vector.

```
>map_chr(a, ~ getBestMatch(.x, charvec))
[1] "brown dog"        "lazy cat"         "white dress"      "I know that"     
[5] "I know that"      "new building"     "excuse me please"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I have edited the answer to make it more clear. So, I want to fuzzy match between each element in mylist (character vector) to each element in charvec (character string). A match between all strings in "a" and "brown dog" should give me the max distance among the 7 scores. And it should loop through both the rows and the columns. I apologize if I was not clear enough before.

Comment: I'm sorry but you have the answer almost right there in front of you - you only need to add looping over list elements.... Oh and if you want just a score instead of the matched word then just remove set_names and names lines from getBestMAtch function.

Comment: I think I'm getting the position of matched words with your suggestion                  map_chr(a, ~ getBestMatch(.x, charvec))
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "4" "7" "5"

Comment: Oh right since you want just a value and not the position then you should also change  which.max to max.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringdist)

dist <- stringdistmatrix( df$text, charvec ,method = "lcs" )
row.names( dist ) <- as.character( df$text )
colnames( dist ) <- charvec
```

I used `lcs` in this example; **L**ongest **C**ommon **S**ubstring distance.

I encourage you to check out other methods. `?"stringdist-metrics"`

the lower the distance, the better the match...

```
> dist
#               brown dog lazy cat white dress I know that excuse me please tall person new building good example green with envy zebra crossing
# brown fox             4       15          16          14               23          14           17           15              18             15
# lazy dog              9        6          15          15               20          13           14           18              21             14
# white cat            14        9           8          12               19          16           17           17              16             17
# I don't know         13       16          19          11               24          17           18           20              19             20
# sunset               13       12          13          13               16          13           14           16              17             16
# never mind           13       16          15          17               18          15           12           18              15             14
# excuse me            16       15          14          18                7          16           17           13              16             17
# very late            14        9          14          14               15          16           15           15              16             17
# do not cross         13       16          13          15               22          15           20           18              21             14
# sunrise              14       15          14          16               17          14           15           17              16             17
# long vacation        14       11          22          16               25          16           17           19              20             19
# toy example          16       13          16          16               15          14           19            5              20             21
# green apple          14       15          16          16               15          16           17           11              12             21
# tall building        16       17          18          20               25          12            7           21              22             17
# good rating          14       13          18          14               23          16           15           11              18             15
# accommodating        16       13          22          18               23          18           17           17              24             15
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I have edited the answer to make it more clear. So, I want to fuzzy match between each element in mylist (character vector) to each element in charvec (character string). A match between all strings in "a" and "brown dog" should give me the max distance among the 7 scores. And it should loop through both the rows and the columns. I apologize if I was not clear enough before.